Show up on PR and wait for another action
My repo is set up with 2 branches, develop and production.
On PRs that are set to merge into production, I want to trigger a deployment and then an end to end test on that deployment on every push to the PR.
The deployment action is already set up to run like so and works:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "develop"

The end to end test action successfully runs after the deployment with the following code:
workflow_run:
    workflows: [Develop Deploy]
    types: [completed]
    branches: [develop]

My problem is that although the end to end test action fires at the correct time, it no longer show up as a check on the PR. After researching, I've only seen one solution:

Run the end to end test on push and repeatedly ping github to see if the deploy action has completed before starting
I would have to pay for the minutes and this logic is kind of gross

Any ideas on how to have the end to end test dependent on the deploy, and have them both show up on the PR and run after push?
